# DJANGO dynamic views and forms

Tags: xml, django, django-forms, django-views

I have some XML files uploaded for the users. This files are templates to make request to a different web services.
I want to know if is possible read the file and create a django form based on the fields of the XML.

If this is possible, What I need to receive the values from the form to rewrite or create XML file that I will send as request to the web service.

For example in other projects to receive values from a form I use

For GET method:

> REQUEST.GET.GET('name_of_argument')

For POST method:

> REQUEST.POST.GET('name_of_argument')

But in this cases I know the name of the argument.
In the xml files there's at least 5 arguments with different names.
How can I read the name of the arguments and use it in the view to get data to pass to the web service.

In other words:

if possible creta a django form based in xml file?

If possible get the data from a form in a view without knowing the name of the arguments pass it from the form to the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible. You just parse the XML file, then create a form dynamically. Here's a rough example:

Assume that you got the field names from XML like `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`, then in your form you do:

```
def DynamicForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        field_list = kwargs.pop('field_list', [])
        super(DynamicForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name in field_list:
            # if you get the field type from xml as well you need
            # some if/else here to create the field type
            self.fields[field_name] = forms.CharField()
```

Then in your views.py, you do:

```
def view(request):
    # pseudo code parse_xml
    field_names = parse_xml(xml_file)
    form = DynamicForm(request.POST or None, field_list=field_names)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that approach.

Comment: works perfectly, I only a have a doubt. I can render the form but how I can fetch the data from the arguments in the view if I didn't know the name of the arguments

Comment: You need a loop to get field and value from `form.cleaned_data`, it's a dictionary.

Comment: When I try to validate the form using `form.is_valid()`, I get the error **unhashable type: 'QueryDict'**. and for thata error I can access the cleaned_data